# How to increase Message size in signal 2.2.2

Tags: signalr, size, message

I'm using signalr 2.2.2 to send the current html to a signalr server hosting process to convert to pdf and while doing that keep a progress bar shown on the client side. The issue is signalr has a max message limit of 64kb. How do I increase that? Below is my websocket transport trace log. The target and compilation .net framework is 4.5 so SignalR is using websockets for this.

### transport trace log output:

SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Information: 0 : Connection 2a307c4b-1ef6-4334-a3ef-875e0167ed75 is New.
SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport Verbose: 0 : Sending outgoing message. Connection id: 2a307c4b-1ef6-4334-a3ef-875e0167ed75, transport: WebSocketTransport, message: {"C":"d-3FF6BE97-B,0|C,0|D,1","S":1,"M":[]}
SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport Information: 0 : Abort(2a307c4b-1ef6-4334-a3ef-875e0167ed75)
SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport Information: 0 : CloseSocket(2a307c4b-1ef6-4334-a3ef-875e0167ed75)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Information: 0 : Removing connection 2a307c4b-1ef6-4334-a3ef-875e0167ed75
SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport Information: 0 : End(2a307c4b-1ef6-4334-a3ef-875e0167ed75)
SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport Verbose: 0 : DrainWrites(2a307c4b-1ef6-4334-a3ef-875e0167ed75)
SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport Information: 0 : CompleteRequest (2a307c4b-1ef6-4334-a3ef-875e0167ed75)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Information: 0 : Connection 58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073 is New.
SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport Verbose: 0 : Sending outgoing message. Connection id: 58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073, transport: WebSocketTransport, message: {"C":"d-3FF6BE97-B,0|E,0|F,1","S":1,"M":[]}
SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport Error: 0 : OnError(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073, System.InvalidOperationException: Buffer length exceeded
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.ByteBuffer.Append(Byte[] segment)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.WebSockets.WebSocketMessageReader.d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.WebSockets.WebSocketHandler.d__25.MoveNext())
SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport Information: 0 : CloseSocket(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : Connection 58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073 exists. Closing previous connection.
SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport Information: 0 : End(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport Verbose: 0 : Cancel(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport Verbose: 0 : DrainWrites(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport Information: 0 : CompleteRequest (58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Verbose: 0 : KeepAlive(58e58295-77a1-48d7-bac3-5e7fcbb51073)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property you are looking for is [`MaxIncomingWebSocketMessageSize`](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/b73cbabe69bc48c4cb8d768148e157712a264ce9/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Configuration/IConfigurationManager.cs#L51)
on `GlobalHost.Configuration`.

Comment: Where to set this property ?

Comment: In the `Configuration` method of your `Startup` class.